# I wish to show the users that an item already edited. What visual affordance can be used for this?

Tags: forms, affordance, inline-edit

To have awareness on interacting for the second time, the user is able to differentiate between edited and non edited items.

Here is a picture of the element :

[image]

Comment: Please give more context here. What have you tried? What sort of content are you talking about? Are you looking for an icon? What exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: I am looking for a visual element like an icon or text property which can tell the difference between an already edited item and the rest of the items.

Comment: We can't give icon suggestions as that's not on-topic for this site. However we may be able to give you more general advice on what approach to take. I've reopened it, but if answers just focus on icons then the question may get closed off.

Comment: I am looking for a generic suggestion to achieve this diferentiation actually Icon was one way of doing it.

Comment: Is that a dropdown? What is this element?

Comment: The problem with just making the edited item look different - with a * or font formatting or even with an icon - is that the difference doesn't convey enough information. It says that this item is different, but not that it's edited. You'll have to add a note someplace that explains the meaning of the difference, and I wouldn't trust that people are going to look for or read that note.

Comment: I agree, the asterisk * is a clean way of conveying the information but it has an ambiguity associated with it. @Majo0od it is a list with nested structure and each item is editable in terms of a few properties like name, size, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here on StackExchange the posts have these little notifications: "edited 4 hours ago" (See your original post to see it in action.) That serves double duty by telling us the item has been edited, and when.

In a drop-down list, that would translate into something like one of these:

[image: "edited" Example]
[image: "edited" Example Long]

Answer (score 1):

One design suggestion is to split the table into two tables - one for already-edited and one for non-edited. In this way you can give each table a title to describe its purpose.

Alternatively, keep everything in one table, and place the text "Edited" next to the items which have been edited.

Or perhaps use a tick icon to indicate edited? I personally tend to avoid icons where its meaning could be ambiguous or confusing, which is why it might be better to be explicit with text.

Comment: (I wasn't the downvote) The way interpret the rules if the OP asks for an icon it is off topic, but if the OP asks for a way to accomplish something such as visually distinguishing a field and the answer is an icon, it is perfectly on topic to suggest one.

Comment: @DasBeasto I updated the post to reflect that advice

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the edited items in bold text,i think the edited items should be different but view should not be much different from others